# Can't get my Asp.Net Core project to work published to folder on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

My Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC app works fine when I run it from Visual Studio > IIS Express, but after I publish to folder (c:\inetpub\TSGOnline) (TSGOnline is my solution's name), I just see this error message in the browser:
[It tells me that changing environment to Production, it will work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Gfx.png)

But in Visual Studio, I have indeed set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production.
[As far as I can tell, the environment is Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIS8f.png)

My OS is Windows 10, IIS version is 10.0.15063.0.

Program.cs:

```
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    namespace TSGOnline
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            }

            public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseStartup()
                    .Build();
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using TSGOnline.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace TSGOnline
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                services.AddMvc();
            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseBrowserLink();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                }

                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=TSG}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

My csproj:
[I wasn't able to paste it as code, so had to use image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiewN.png)

I have spent two days googling, trying to figure this one out, but being a total noob, I may not always know when the answers are right in front of me ... Please help?

Comment: Nowhere in your images it is written that changing to Production environment will make it work.

Comment: I realise that now. It just says I will get a detailed error message. Sorry for that.

Comment: You'll get a Detailed error message if you change your environment to DEVELOPMENT.

Answer (score 0):

For `IIS` application. You need to set that variable either in `IIS` application or system variables.

Please look at chapter setting environments

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Windows

To set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for the current session, if the app is started using dotnet run, the following commands are used

```
Command Line:
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

PowerShell:
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

These commands take effect only for the current window. When the window is closed, the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` setting reverts to the default setting or machine value.

In order to set the value globally on Windows open the Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings and add or edit the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value.

Per IIS Application Pool:

If you need to set environment variables for individual apps running in isolated Application Pools (supported on IIS 10.0+), see the `AppCmd.exe` command section of the Environment Variables [`<environmentVariables>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/environmentvariables/) topic in the IIS reference documentation.

Comment: I don't understand how to set the environment for a window. How do I enter command line commands to an instance of Chrome?

Comment: No, you are doing it in windows command line. Please read that article carefully